# 404 Not Found for Web API Route

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api-routing

I make a call to an ASP.Net Web API which returns 404 Not found. The controller is recognized but the action is not found.

I have tried using attribute routing and `[HttpGet]` for the action. I've also tried using standard API routing in the WebAPI config file. I've even tried combining the two.

```
//[HttpGet]
//[Route("api/User")]
protected IHttpActionResult GetEmployeeHierarchyList()
{
  // ...
  return Json(results);
}
```

```csharp
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "GetEmployeeHierarchyListTwo",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { action = "GetEmployeeHierarchyList", }
);
```

```js
return fetch("/api/User/" + api, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'credentials': 'include'
  }
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
```

I expect the action to return a string to be handled by the fetch call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `GetEmployeeHierarchyList()` method int the controller public.

Comment: OMG Thank you! So embarrassed!

Answer (score 0):

***This should workfine:***

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/User")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEmployeeHierarchyList()
    {
      // ...
      return Json(results);
    }
```